# What are the steps to effectively learn english vocabulary through contextual learning?

Tags: vocabulary, learning, learning-methods

The most effective way to learn new English words, idioms, phrases, and expand one's vocabulary is through a technique called **contextual learning**. This technique involves understanding new words and phrases within the context of sentences or stories, rather than in isolation. But what is the best strategy for applying this learning method?

Here are the steps I take: First, I compile a thorough list of English words that are new to me. These could be words I've encountered in books, articles, or conversations that I didn't fully comprehend.

Once I have this list, I seek assistance from **Copilot, an AI assistant**. I request Copilot to translate these words into Persian, my mother tongue. Comprehending the meanings of these words in my native language allows me to better understand their subtleties.

In addition to the translations, I also ask Copilot to provide English definitions of these words. This aids me in understanding how these words are utilized in the context of the English language.

But I don't stop there. I also request Copilot to compose a story in English that incorporates all the words from my list. This story acts as a practical demonstration of how these words can be applied in real-world contexts. Reading these words within a story makes them more memorable and enhances my understanding of their usage.

This method has been quite successful for me. It enables me to memorize the words after just one reading within the context of the story. The combination of understanding the translations in my native language, the definitions in English, and seeing the words used in a story, offers a comprehensive learning experience.

However, I'm always receptive to enhancements. Are my steps accurate? Is there a more effective way to learn new English words using the contextual learning method? I'm keen to receive any suggestions or feedback.

Comment: If you are really able to form these sentences I don't think you need to seek help from us. You already know a lot of new words.